# QPainter colored text (syntax coloring)

Tags: c++, qt, syntax-highlighting, qpainter

I have a custom Qt widget which I used to display disassembly and I am looking to add syntax coloring to it.

Currently, I simply set the `QPen` to a solid color, construct the text I want to display, and render it to the `QPainter` at the appropriate coordinates.

The question is, what is the best approach to adding syntax coloring? I've thought of a few:

1. I could simply divide the coloring into logical blocks, each preceded by setting the QPen to the desired color.
2. I could have special escape characters which represent a change in the color palette, and render 1 character at a time.
3. I could do a modification of #1 and create a list of `std::pair<QColor, QString>`, then I could simply iterate the list setting the color and drawing the text as I pop items off the front of the list.
4. Something entirely different?

I know that each of the 3 approaches I've listed will technically work, but I'm looking for a very efficient solution. This code will be called a lot. And since this is an interactive debugger, if this code is slow, someone rapidly stepping or tracing will see a visible slowdown.

**EDIT:** I'm aware of `QSyntaxHighlighter` and `QTextDocument`. The main issue is that these don't generally suite my purposes very well. I have several columns which all have dividers and can be slid back and forth. To give you an idea, Here's a link to a [screenshot of my debugger](http://www.codef00.com/img/debugger.png). As you can see it isn't really like a text document at all. In fact it is closer to a list or table. But there is already a bunch of custom drawing going on making a normal `QTextDocument` somewhat impractical.

**EDIT**: I was incorrect, It seems that `QTextDocument` can render directly to a `QPainter`. Looks like what I need!

**EDIT**: It is unclear how to control where and how `QTextDocument` or `QTextLayout` will draw on a `QPainter`. I've attempted to use them to no avail. So if someone could provide a rudimentary example, that would be very helpful.

**EDIT**: I was eventually able to get what I wanted using something like this:

```
painter.setPen(default_color);
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setDefaultFont(font());
doc.setDocumentMargin(0);
doc.setPlainText(text);
highlighter_->setDocument(&doc);

painter.save();
painter.translate(x, y);
QAbstractTextDocumentLayout::PaintContext context;
context.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, painter.pen().color());
doc.draw(&painter, context);
painter.restore();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt provides a [`QSyntaxHighlighter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) that is probably exactly what you want.  `QSyntaxHighlighter` uses a [`QTextDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) to mark each block of code with a specific state which can be associated with a specific presentation [format](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcharformat.html).

The documentation on `QSyntaxHighlighter` provides a sample demonstrating how this may be accomplished and does some nice things:

- Separates the model from presentation
- Separates the formatting into different reusable classes (if implemented as such)
- Supports the [State](http://exciton.cs.rice.edu/JavaResources/DesignPatterns/StatePat.htm) design pattern if useful to your language

Comment: Also, why did you community wiki your answer? You won't get the rep points for your answer...

Comment: Woah, I just noticed QTextDocument has a drawContents which draws to a QPainter. Now *that* is helpful! I think we may have a winner.

Comment: Re: community wiki... because I'm still a noob and am trying to figure out how SO works :(.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use either [QTextEdit](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtextedit.html) or directlay its underlining engine [QTextDocument](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtextdocument.html).